# Unable to take screenshots using Xamarin.UITest

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, calabash, xamarin.uitest

I'm running Xamarin.UITest tests on Windows 7, using an Andorid emulator and Android device. In both cases I'm unable to take screenshots.

I'm initialising things like this:

```cs
ConfigureApp
    .Android
    .ApkFile(apkPath)
    .EnableLocalScreenshots()
    .StartApp();
```

And taking a screenshot like this:

```cs
App.Screenshot("App Started");
```

However, when calling `App.Screenshot` I get this exception:

```
System.Exception : Error while performing Screenshot("App Started")
  ----> System.Exception : Failed to create C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\xamarin.uitest\3.0.3\lib\net45\screenshot-1.png. You may need to set the working directory, which can be done using System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory().
   at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With[T](Func`1 func, Object[] args, String memberName)
   at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp.Screenshot(String title)
   at ACME.App.UITest.BaseUITest.BeforeEachTest() in C:\ACME\ACME.Application.UITest\BaseUITest.cs:line 29
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.TaskAwaitAdapter.GenericAdapter`1.GetResult() in D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\TaskAwaitAdapter.cs:line 99
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke) in D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\AsyncToSyncAdapter.cs:line 60
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.SetUpTearDownItem.RunSetUpOrTearDownMethod(TestExecutionContext context, MethodInfo method) in D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\Commands\SetUpTearDownItem.cs:line 111
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.SetUpTearDownItem.RunSetUp(TestExecutionContext context) in D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\Commands\SetUpTearDownItem.cs:line 68
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.SetUpTearDownCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0(TestExecutionContext context) in D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\Commands\SetUpTearDownCommand.cs:line 48
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Execute>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\Commands\BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.cs:line 58
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action) in D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\Commands\BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.cs:line 73
--Exception
   at Xamarin.UITest.Android.JavaScreenshotTaker.Screenshot(String title)
   at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp.<>c__DisplayClass84_0.<Screenshot>b__0()
   at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With[T](Func`1 func, Object[] args, String memberName)
```

Looking at the log file that's generated, I see:

```
Could not take screenshot
java.io.IOException: EOF
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:874)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:333)
    at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source)
    at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source)
    at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source)
```

What I've tried:

- Setting a different directory using `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()` - this seems to be ignored, as I see the same path in the Exception regardless (`C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\xamarin.uitest\...`)
- Giving the `Everyone` group access to the path `C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\xamarin.uitest\3.0.3\lib\net45\` - no effect
- Ensuring that tests can write files to the path above - they can, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue
- Updating to the latest dev build of Xamarin.UITest, `3.0.4-dev1` - same result

Comment: I will  try it myself , if I have any result I will come back asap.

Comment: Try adding `SCREENSHOT_VIA_USB="false"` at runtime, example:`calabash-android run path/to/apk.apk -p android SCREENSHOT_VIA_USB="false"`. Have you updated to the latest package version?

Comment: @Saamer as my question says, I've tried with the latest at the time, `3.0.4-dev1` - now `dev2` is out, I'll give that a try too. I run tests using a test runner (e.g. Visual Studio, Rider), so don't call `calabash-android` myself (is this even still a thing now it's "Xamarin.UITest"?). Haven't come across `SCREENSHOT_VIA_USB` before - is it an environment variable, or something I can set in code? Also, are there any docs about it?

Comment: There is a issue about this: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/479

Comment: @JessieZhang yes, I commented on it myself a month ago :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem this week, and it was related to a security improvement to avoid taking screenshots on the app.
If you did this (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96818/disable-the-screenshot-functionality-in-xamarin-forms-application) probably that is the problem. With just a #if !DEBUG you could fix it.

Hope to help someone.